# how to re-enable copy and paste default after doing event.preventDefault()

Tags: angularjs, copy, paste, preventdefault

I know this exact question was asked here, but those questions are not helped to me. I applied prevent default for copy and paste how to re-enable it.

```
if(event.type === "copy") {
        scope.$apply(function (){
          scope.$eval(attrs.ngKeystrokecopy);
        });
        event.preventDefault();
      }
      if(event.type === "paste") {
        scope.$apply(function (){
          scope.$eval(attrs.ngKeystrokepaste);
        });
      }
```

Comment: Did you try remove the event.preventDefault(); line? Try commenting that out and see what happens.

Comment: @jojo if i remove that line it will work fine but coming to my requirement the line is need.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle that shows this behavior?